# Paginate with category filter?

Tags: filter, category

Below is my paginate code and it's working fine.

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('products').limit(9) as entriesOnPage %}

{% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
    <div class="product-box">
        <div class="product">
            <p class="product-name">
                <a href="{{ entry.category.first().url }}">{{ entry.category.first().title }}</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% if paginate.nextUrl %}
    <a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}">Next</a>
{% endif %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

Below is my code to display specific category data with pagination. and it's not working.

```
{% set requestCategory = craft.request.getLastSegment() %}

{% paginate craft.entries.section('products').find({
    search: 'categories:' ~ requestCategory,
  }).limit(9) as entriesOnPage %}

{% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
    <div class="product-box">
        <div class="product">
            <p class="product-name">
                <a href="{{ entry.category.first().url }}">{{ entry.category.first().title }}</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% if paginate.nextUrl %}
    <a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}">Next</a>
{% endif %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

i want to add category filter on that but not working how can i add a category filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the relatedTo() filter as explained here:

http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entries-related-to-category

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('products').relatedTo(requestCategory).limit(9) as entriesOnPage %}
```